# Is it a good idea to create fields through a database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm a novice react developer working on a project, and was wondering if I could get some advice. This project is essentially converting a very complicated and large spreadsheet into a nice application. I'm also using material-ui for some of the components. The reason I'm here is because the way I currently have my fields set up feels wrong, and I was hoping some more experienced people could weigh in.

Essentially, I have all the data that creates each field in a psql database table (see the fieldData variable in the codesandbox) . I pull that data in via useEffect and axios, and run it through a function which outputs the fields (63 at the moment). I also have a reducer which controls the state of the components so I can add them together, and submit the data to the database, which I haven't implemented yet.

The reason I am running it through the database instead of just creating each component individually is so that later on, you can change/add fields from inside the application instead of having to edit the javascript. However, it feels like this is inefficient, or there's a better solution that I'm missing. I appreciate any help or feedback, thanks!

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-dewdney-xx8w4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Some deprecated errors in your sandbox console. ,,, Other than that, without the "very complicated and large spreadsheet", its hard to recommend a schema for the database.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the errors, but I didn't think that it mattered too much since I don't have those on my actual application. The question is less about what schema to have, since I already have one in place, but more if I should be storing the data that creates each individual field in the database, excluding the data that is inputted by the user and stored in a seperate table.

Comment: By this `if I should be storing the data that creates each individual field` can you provide an example of how that data looks like?

Comment: I mentioned it at the start of the second paragraph, but in the fieldData variable in App.js in the codesandbox, the commented part shows what columns I currently have.

Comment: Searching sandbox where you are verse on that usage, is not same as posting code on SO where we here are verse with it

Comment: Am voting to close

Comment: Sorry that this question is frustrating you. The point of the question wasn't to talk about the schema, but to ask if it's a good idea to build fields through a database. Also, the sandbox link still works for me in an incognito window, I didn't delete anything. The code works fine for me, it's more the concept that I was asking about. Also, what do you mean by verse? I don't fully understand that sentence.

Comment: `The code works fine for me` wont be helpful for historical purposes when the code link you provide eventually wont work, as in eventually be a dead link. Is all, i meant. There was no frustration whatsoever, just a heads up